# Centering inline-block image and text

Tags: html, css

I have an image placed next to text, both inline-block elements, and am having difficulty centering them. I've tried including both in a div and applying `text-align:center`, but nothing changes. I've also thought about changing h1 to display:block and then applying `text-align:center`, but I'd like both the text and title to be centered relative to the content below it, instead of the whole thing being slightly off-centered from the placement of the image.
HTML:

```
<img src="logo.svg">
<h1 id="logo-text">TITLE</h1>
```

CSS:

```
header img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
}

header h1#logo-text {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
header img {
  height: 50px;
}
header h1#logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200">
  <h1 id="logo-text">TITLE</h1>
</header>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam hendrerit eu diam et dapibus. Vestibulum mattis augue et gravida tincidunt. Etiam congue nisl id sem ornare, ac dignissim est aliquet. Aenean at venenatis est. Maecenas nunc tellus, imperdiet
  nec eros eu, ultrices euismod turpis. Donec faucibus gravida lectus, sit amet maximus nulla posuere id. Aliquam pulvinar dui non arcu tincidunt, nec maximus sem pretium. Sed aliquet dolor ac lectus aliquam, sit amet aliquam tortor imperdiet. Proin vitae
  diam tincidunt elit lobortis ultricies. Praesent tristique ex scelerisque posuere placerat.</p>

<p>Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur vel dictum odio. In congue egestas odio at lacinia. Aliquam vehicula felis nec faucibus vestibulum. Morbi sed augue accumsan, eleifend elit eget, luctus urna. Integer quis facilisis est. Ut at pretium erat. Mauris at neque
  justo. Ut eu ligula pretium, volutpat justo quis, malesuada turpis. Integer id consectetur urna. Etiam mauris enim, mattis ac finibus id, volutpat eget sapien. Donec quis libero sapien.</p>
```

You can use `flex` to position it in the center, without any dirty hacks. No extra mark-up required.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
}

header h1#logo-text {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<header style="text-align:center;" >
  <img src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif">
  <div style="clear:both;display:block;" ></div>
  <h1 id="logo-text">TITLE</h1>      
</header>
```

Comment: A code-only answer is completely useless for non-experienced users.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css rule.

```
header{text-align: center;}
```